# footer not falling to bottom of page

Tags: html, css

Been having trouble with this footer for a while. direct link to page [here](http://gioventunyc.com/pages/shipping-and-returns). There should be two footer states:

1. When content height is less than page height, the footer should stick to the bottom of the window, as it does currently
2. When the content height is greater than the window height, (see pic), the footer isn't falling to the bottom of the content.

**1.** works but **2.** doesn't. Pic [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mwXaB.png) of the issue and this is what happens when you scroll [pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lm7it.png)
any ideas how to fix?

CSS:

```
footer {
   width: 100%;
   float: left;
   clear: both;
   height: 50px;
   position: relative;
   bottom: 0;
   overflow: hidden;
   margin-top: -50px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is not with footer div, the issue is with the preview DOM element `#wrapper`

change the `height` property of the `#wrapper` to `min-height`

```
#wrapper {
   min-height: 100%;
}
```

also i have few suggestion, float and clear doesn't make sense on `footer` remove it.